# MODIS data for entire Earth Surface with ModisDownload in R

Tags: r, modis, ndvi, modis-reprojection-tool

I am trying to use the `ModisDownload` function from the `rts` package to download, mosaic and reproject NDVI data from MODIS for the entire Earth surface. I have successfully done that for a subset around Africa using the following code

```
ModisDownload(x="MOD13Q1", h=c(16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23) ,v=c(5,6,7,8,9), version = '006', dates=c('2000.02.01', '2000.02.29'),
            MRTpath=path, mosaic=T, proj=T, bands_subset="1 0 0 0 0 0", proj_type="GEO",
            proj_params="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0", datum="WGS84", pixel_size=0.01, delete = T)
```

The output can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yxkn17y7cplchs/MOD13Q1_2000-02-18.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif?dl=0) or in the figure attached below. For the whole surface of Earth, my intuition was to change the `h` and `v` parameters to cover the whole MODIS sinusoidal grid, hence `h = 0:35` and `v=0:17`. After downloading the raw `.hdr` files, the reprojection tool crashes. Does someone know if the `h` and `v` parameters are set correctly for the whole (-180,180;-90,90) surface?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Downloading data for the whole planet using MODIS MOD13Q1 250m product will generate quite a large dataset and that's probably why `ModisDownload` collapsed.

Instead, you can try to use `MODIStsp` package which is much more robust (in my opinion) and holds very advanced features for downloading, mosaicking, and processing MODIS data.

Check it out here:
https://github.com/lbusett/MODIStsp
and here
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MODIStsp/index.html